# Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: addons. Please verify its path and try again

Tags: linux

Un saludo, estoy tratando de instalar estas dependencias y se me presenta este error:

> Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for
>   repository: addons. Please verify its path and try again

la distribucion que estoy utilizando Red hat enterprise Linux Server release 6.2, quisiera su ayuda